# How do I round a double to 0.00005?

Tags: c, rounding, c89

I have a double and I want to round down to values 0.00000/0.00005 using C89/ANSI C.
So:

```
1.10984 becomes 1.10980
1.10985 becomes 1.10985
1.10986 becomes 1.10985
1.10988 becomes 1.10985
1.10989 becomes 1.10985
1.10990 becomes 1.10990
1.10991 becomes 1.10990
```

I have tried:

```
roundedDouble = doubleToRound - (doubleToRound % 0.00005);
```

But % operator only works with integers.

Solution shall work also with the following rounding down cases:

```
0.000000 / 0.000025 / 0.000050 / 0.000075
```

and

```
0.00001 / 0.00002 / 0.00003 / 0.00004 / ... / 0.00008 / 0.00009
```

Comment: [`fmod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) works with `double`.

Comment: The solution will certainly be approximate as typical `double` cannot represent `0.00005` _exactly_.

Comment: I will try fmod() and see what happens with the representation inaccuracy of double.